# knitr using old source files to run code chunks

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I am working on a package in RStudio and have started to work on documentation. Both README.md and a vignette knitted just fine initially, using the knitr menu option in RStudio. Over the past days, however, I have made some changes to my code, including changing the name of a key S4 class that is exported (and the file that contains it) and thus used extensively in sample code in both the README file and vignette. I have `R CMD check`ed my code with 0 errors, 0 warnings and 0 notes and the code runs just fine in the console.

`knitr`, on the other hand, barfs out with an error code saying it cannot find my new class (in a renamed file etc) and provides me with a detailed message of what it is missing and where in which file the offence is taking place, for both README and vignette (they have an identical basic example which comes early in both files). I recognise the code snippet that `knitr` chokes on, but it is from my old code. The file in question currently has updated code.

Checking previous versions on GitHub indeed shows the offending code at the correct line **in an old version of the file**.

I have restarted RStudio, rebuilt the documentation, cleared the knitr cache, but the problem persists. Any suggestions on how I can make `knitr` use the current code base?

Running `R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) -- "Beagle Scouts"` in `RStudio Version 2023.06.0+421 (2023.06.0+421)` with `knitr 1.43`.

Comment: You don't describe how you are running `knitr`.

Comment: @user2554330 I added some clarifications

Comment: It sounds as though you haven't installed the current version of the package.  In RStudio, run Build | Install.  Add `sessionInfo()` to your code to get R to display the version number of your package that is running.

Comment: Perhaps you were using `devtools::load_all()` or some related function.  That is just for testing, it doesn't install the package.

Comment: Build | Install did the trick. Make that an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you haven't installed the current version of the package. In RStudio, run `Build | Install`.  Perhaps you were using `devtools::load_all()` or some related function. That is just for testing, it doesn't install the package.

To check that things are working, make sure your new code has a new version number, and add `sessionInfo()` to a code chunk in your document to get R to display the version number of your package that is running.

Comment: It's a bit odd though that `knitr` would require the package to be installed rather than using the active project. I'm pretty sure that initially `knitr` worked without installing the package.

Comment: RStudio usually runs `knitr` in a separate R session so that results are reproducibe.  The `devtools::load_all()` function just loads functions into the current session.  You'd probably get things working the way you expected if you called `rmarkdown::render()` or `knitr::knit()` directly within a session.